# How to create NSTableview with Custom Cell using Binding

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings, custom-cell

I am new to Cocoa. I successfully created a TableView with two colomns , both containing text, using NSArrayController and binding . Now I want to achieve the same for custom TableView. My TableView contains two colomns, one should contain image and the other one should contain image description. I want to populate my table using binding . Can any one tell me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps:

In Xib/Nib files:

1. Take NSArrayController.
2. Take NSTableView and take two columns.
3. In first column drag NSImageCell and second one will be by default NSTextCell.
4. Now bind:

   - First arraycontroller to your NSObject or FileOwners.
   - Your mutablearray to arraycontroller .
   - Tableview first column to array controller inside whose controller key should be arrangesObjects and modelkeypath should be img.
   - Tableview second column to array controller inside whose controller key should be arrangesObjects and modelkeypath should be desc.

(Note: While binding to table columns please check one option Validates Immediately, if you are using >10.6 os version)

In header file:

```
NSString *img;
NSString *desc;
NSMutableArray *arr;
IBOutlet NSArrayController *arrCont;
@property (readwrite,retain) NSString *img;
@property (readwrite,retain) NSString *desc;
@property (readwrite,retain) NSMutableArray *arr;
```

In implementation file:

```
self.arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *imageName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourImageName" ofType:@"tiff"];
NSImage *photoImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imageName];
NSMutableDictionary *dc = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dc setObject:photoImage forKey:@"img"];
[dc setObject:@"noImage" forKey:@"desc"];
[arr addObject:dc];
[self setArr:arr];
```